# How to add svn plug-in to Eclipse Juno in RHEL 6.5 using command line?

Tags: svn, eclipse-plugin, redhat

I have installed Eclipse Juno on RHEL 6.5 64 Bit Workstation. Now I have to add svn plug-ins to Eclipse using command line, I dont have access to GUI Interface.

Any idea how to achieve this through command line?